# Program to make measurements on images (ex. maps) and list them

Tags: images, cad

I'm looking for a program (preferably open source/free) that would allow me to import images and take measurements.

I want to measure a lot of points and generate reports of the total length of all points.

It's to calculate total length of electrical circuits on a project.